# Im having problems with loops

Tags: php, foreach

[image: Image of table]

Table:

```
cartId   cusid
2         3
3         3

2         4
3         4

2         5
3         5
```

```
$cartid = array(2,3);
$cusid = array(3,4,5);
```

Pls is there a way I can achieve the above table using foreach loop?
I tried this

```
foreach($cartid as $index=>$cartid2){
    foreach($cusid as $index=>$cusid2){
     echo "$cartid2 ===== $cusid2";
    }
}
```

But didn't work, its saying offset. Pls I need help. View the image for better understanding

Comment: looks like the code you have posted should run. Where are you seeing the offset error?: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1b6074a53e0d4ebf64f871c409f1da6a11bd49bc

Comment: You're using the name `$index` variable in both loops. The first array has 2 items, the second 3. This is the cause of your error. Use different variable names.

Comment: or remove `$index` if you're not using it.

Comment: What do you mean by "its saying offset"? What is the exact error message?

Comment: Why is your table different in the image than the text?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems with your code. Firstly you are overwriting `$index` in the inner loop (however, since `$index` is not used, that's not a big deal). Secondly your loops are nested incorrectly, your outer loop should be on `$cusid` and the inner loop on `$cartid`. Try this:

```
$cartid = array(2,3);
$cusid = array(3,4,5);

echo "cartid\tcusid\n";
foreach($cusid as $cus){
    foreach($cartid as $cart){
        echo "$cart\t$cus\n";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
cartid cusid
2      3
3      3

2      4
3      4

2      5
3      5
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/p0vCR)

Answer (score 0):

Nick thanks for your answer, it really worked for me, i appreciate so much. I had to use an if statement to get exactly what i wanted.

```
foreach($rider_id1 as $rider_id2){   
    foreach($cart_id1 as $cart_id2){
        if($rider_id2!=""){
            if($cart_id2!=""){
                echo "$cart_id2 ====== $rider_id2<br>";
            }
        }
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Thanks dude!